# Using IEnumerable<> and creating a property with its type

Tags: c#, linq, interface, viewmodel, ienumerable

I have not used Linq much nor have I used the IEnumberable class. Below is my code and explanations on what I am having trouble with.

```
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    #region Constructors

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<IEmailAddressesProvider> AddressProviders { get; set; }

    #endregion
```

These are my properties that I need to use in the EmailService Class. This is a collection of the email address providers.

I need to use what is stored there in and basically connect it to the ViewModel as I did with these other properties in the next section of this code.

```
IUserInteractionService uiService = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<IUserInteractionService>();
            IEmailSetupProvider provider = new EmailSetupProvider();
            EmailView ev = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<EmailView>();

            ev.ViewModel.ProviderName = AddressProviders;
            ev.ViewModel.Provider = provider;
            ev.ViewModel.Bcc = bccAddress;
            ev.ViewModel.Cc = ccAddress;
            ev.ViewModel.ToAddress = toAddress;
            ev.ViewModel.Body = body;
            ev.ViewModel.Subject = subject;
            ev.ViewModel.Attachments = attachments;

            return uiService.ShowDialog(ev, RegionNames.MainRegion);
        }
```

Where it says "Address Providers is where I am trying to create this property.

IEmailAddressesProvider Interface:

```
public interface IEmailAddressesProvider
{
    string ProviderName { get; }
    IEnumerable<EmailAddress> GetEmailUsers();
}
```

GetEmailUsers Method(Just in case it is relevant):

```
[Export(typeof(IEmailAddressesProvider))]
public class EmailAddressProvider : IEmailAddressesProvider
{
    #region Private Properties

    private static readonly IEncryptionService encryptionService = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<IEncryptionService>();

    #endregion

    public string ProviderName
    {
        get { return "Alliance Users"; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<EmailAddress> GetEmailUsers()
    {
        IUserRepository userRepo = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<IUserRepository>();
        IEnumerable<User> users = userRepo.GetAllUsers().Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false).OrderBy(a => a.UserID).AsEnumerable();

        List<EmailAddress> AddressList = new List<EmailAddress>();

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            if (user.DisplayName != null && user.EmailAddress != null && user.DisplayName != string.Empty && user.EmailAddress != string.Empty)
                AddressList.Add(new EmailAddress() { DisplayName = encryptionService.DecryptString(user.DisplayName), Email = encryptionService.DecryptString(user.EmailAddress) });
        }

        AddressList.OrderBy(u => u.DisplayName);

        return AddressList;
    }
}
```

Code specifically for ProviderName (used in EmailAddressesProvider.cs):

```
[Export(typeof(IEmailAddressesProvider))]
public class EmailAddressProvider : IEmailAddressesProvider
{
    #region Private Properties

    private static readonly IEncryptionService encryptionService = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<IEncryptionService>();

    #endregion

    public string ProviderName
    {
        get { return "Alliance Users"; }
    }
}
```

If you need to see anymore of my code, such as the interfaces or the viewmodel, please let me know. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: But what is the problem? `ProviderName` seems to be a single provider, hence a `IEmailAddressesProvider`. So do you want one name of all available `AddressProviders`, if so, which one?

Comment: I believe it will only show one of them and I think which one will be determined by a different set of code. I am going to post my interface that will be used.

Comment: More code has been added

Comment: @JLott - Even with the additional code, I still don't know what the question is.  Are you getting a compile-time error? Do you not know how to do something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your example is concerned, you can think of `IEnumerable<T>` as being pretty much synonymous with `List<T>`: it's a collection of objects; it could be just one, it could be none, it could be a hundred.  There's more to `IEnumerable` than that, but for your purposes that's as much as you need to think about.

In this code:

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<IEmailAddressesProvider> AddressProviders { get; set; }
```

you're asking MEF to gather all the exported implementations of `IEmailAddressesProvider`.  What you get back is a collection of objects: even if it finds just one, you still get a collection with only one element.  In this later line:

```
ev.ViewModel.ProviderName = AddressProviders;
```

I'm guessing that the left hand side is expecting a `string`, but the right hand side is a collection of `IEmailAddressesProvider`.  Apart from the fact that you probably actually want the `ProviderName` property of the `IEmailAddressesProvider` and not the whole object, you also need to say which object in the collection to use.  There are two ways you might deal with this:

1. **If you know that there will only be one implementation of `IEmailAddressesProvider`**, then change `ImportMany` to `Import` like so

   ```
   [Import]
   public IEmailAddressesProvider AddressProviders { get; set; }
   ```

   and change that other assignment to `ev.ViewModel.ProviderName = AddressProviders.ProviderName`.  Note that this will break as soon as you export a second implementation of `IEmailAddressesProvider`, so only do this if you really know there can only be one.
2. **If there may be several implementations of `IEmailAddressesProvider`**, then you need to find the specific one you want.  You would query the `AddressProviders` collection with something like `FirstOrDefault` (as the other answers have said) to find the right object and then use the `ProviderName` property from that result.  It's not possible to say much more about the query you need from the code you've provided.

Comment: I was trying to implement this code: I receive this error: Error 24 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Alliance.Library.Email.IEmailAddressesProvider>' does not contain a definition for 'ProviderName' and no extension method 'ProviderName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Alliance.Library.Email.IEmailAddressesProvider>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\TFS-Alliance\Suite\Main\Source\Core\Core\Services\EmailService.cs 88 58 Core (Common\Core\Core)

Comment: Which of the two were you trying to implement - option #1 or #2?

Comment: I actually ended up figuring it out... ended up being a mistake in one of my data types, but I did end up going this route instead of another one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing, you want a  single `IEmailAddressesProvider` from the `AddressProviders` which is determined by the `ProviderName` property in the interface and the variable `provider`.

If that is true, you can use [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) which returns the first matching AddressProvider or `null` if no was found with the given `ProviderName`:

```
// ...
ev.ViewModel.ProviderName = AddressProviders
    .FirstOrDefault(ap => ap.ProviderName == yourProviderName);
ev.ViewModel.Provider = provider;
// ...
```

Comment: What exactly is FirstOrDefault? I am receiving this error: Error 322 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Alliance.Library.Email.IEmailAddressesProvider>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Alliance.Library.Email.IEmailAddressesProvider>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\TFS-Alliance\Suite\Main\Source\Core\Core\Services\EmailService.cs 87 58 Core (Common\Core\Core)
Sorry for the bad formatting....

Comment: I have linked msdn in my answer. It's an extesnion method and it should work with your `IEnumerable<Alliance.Library.Email.IEmailA‌​ddressesProvider>`. Since you're already using other linq methods like `OrderBy` i wonder why you get this exception. Maybe becaue you have forgotten to add `using System.Linq;` in this class.

Comment: @JLott can you confirm that Tim's guess is correct. If so you might want to update your question.

Comment: Yes that was causing the error on FirstOrDefaile not I am getting: Error 322 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'Alliance.Library.Email.IEmailSetupProvider'

Comment: @JLott: Then replace `provider` with the name of the provider of type `string`. You have't mentioned it. Edited my answer.

Comment: Alright I put another section of code up that explains ProviderName that might allow you to help me more effectively. There are so many pieces to this that it is hard for me to tell what is even going on. Obviously I am updating someone else's code, or I would know how everything worked together.

Comment: @JLott: No, that doesn't help since you had already provided this code(look for `Just in case it is relevant`). It would help if you would tell what you want to use for `yourProviderName`(in my code). But have you understood what my code does?

Comment: Yes I understand, but I cannot even find the value for "yourProviderName", probably because I haven't created it haha. So maybe the real question is how do I create that property..

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with the above answer try using one of these.

```
ev.ViewModel.ProviderName = AddressProviders.Where(p=> p.ProviderName == provider).Single();
ev.ViewModel.ProviderName = AddressProviders.Where(p=> p.ProviderName == provider).First();
```